# Magento product attributes on catalog view?

Tags: php, magento, attributes

Is it possible to have a list of the available attributes of each product on the catalogue view?

e.g.:

Dog lead: Size attribute: small,medium,large

So on the catalogue page:

Proudct Image
Product Name
AVAILABLE Attibutes
Product Price

So far I have found in App/design/frontend/detault/themename/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<ul class="products-grid">    
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_productCollection as $_product): ?>
        <li class="item">
            <div class="pro_topadst">
            <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image tooltip"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(252); ?>" width="252" height="252" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />

            <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($_product->getName(), null, true) ?>"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></a></h2>
            <?php if($_product->getRatingSummary()): ?>
            <?php echo $this->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_product, 'short') ?>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
            </div>
```

This echo's text out in the correct place, but I have no idea how to call the available attributes, does anyone have any idea or has done this before?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this.  
  $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
        if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
            $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
            // do something with $value here
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());

foreach($_attributes as $_attribute):
    echo $_attribute->getAttributeId();
endforeach
```

This code can be seen at catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

Comment: I tried to just echo this out onto the page but it stopped anything loading after it.

Comment: $attributes = $product->getAttributes();
foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
    if ($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront()) {
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product);
  $code = $attribute->getAttributeCode($product); 
  $label = $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel($product); } endforeach

Comment: Thanks @webgal that one gives me the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDFOREACH in Line 107. Line 107 is the line with "endforeach" on.

Comment: sorry i forgot a semicolon after the endforeach

Comment: Same result with semicolon :(

Comment: oops! just remove the endforeach and add a closing braces }

Comment: That got us a bit further! but now I'm getting the error: 
     
Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributes() on a non-object in /public_html/app/design/frontend/default/templatename/template/catalog/product/list.phtml on line 100

Line 100 is: $attributes = $product->getAttributes();

Comment: oh so you have it as $_product..please replace $product with $_product in the code I sent you. in all the lines

Comment: Ah, sorry to be a pain really novice at this. It's now echoing out the word "Array" and nothing else.

Comment: echo $label." ".$value."<br />"; add this before the 2 closing braces

Comment: Still the same echo of Array. Full code I've got now is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sRxT7/

Comment: you have echo before $attributes = $_product->getAttributes(); remove that and also for $code = line replace $product with $_product. I think you should get the answer now

Comment: Ah sorry I missed them, changed them and now it echo's nothing: http://jsfiddle.net/sRxT7/1/

Comment: ok lets try this. comment the foreach completely and add print_r($attributes);

Comment: Doing this: http://jsfiddle.net/sRxT7/2/ gives me a blank page, doesn't load anything from the site.

Comment: can you tell me what $_productCollection =?

Comment: Sorry do you mean? ?php $_collectionSize = $_productCollection->count() ?> or am I missing what you are asking.

Comment: do you have what $_productCollection is equal to

Comment: Oh sorry yes:     $_productCollection=$this->getLoadedProductCollection();

Comment: ok. so i think that is why the code i gave did not work try this echo $_product->getAttributeText('name');

Comment: Still shows with nothing in the size area. Entire list.phtml not sure if it will help: http://jsfiddle.net/sRxT7/6/

Comment: Blank output again :( Sorry for being a pain.

Comment: Same result :( I'm starting to think this isn't possible ha.

Comment: i m sure its possible. just needs a lot of trial as i m not too sure. try this http://jsfiddle.net/sRxT7/9/

Comment: one last try $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_id')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product)): here put the attribute id of the collar_size and echo

Comment: Do you mean      <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_id')->getFrontend()->getValue(IDHERE$_product)) ?>

if so how do I find the ID of the attribute set?

Comment: no <?php echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('IDHEREattribute_id')->getFrontend()->getValue(‌​$_product)) ?> when you got to the admin panel manage attributes and click on the attribute you want, the link on top will have id/and a number that is the id

Comment: I removed the last ) and it worked. Well it echo'ed the word "no" on all products.

Comment: oh! that means your attribute is not set visible on frontend. click on the attribute in admin panel and set visible on frontend to yes

Comment: Oh, changed that for the attribute set. Still says "no" reindexed the pages as well.

Comment: try this $add = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes();
 $add->setProduct($_product->getId());
 $_additional = $add->getAdditionalData();
 ?>
 <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
        <tr>
            <th><?php echo $_data['label'] ?></th>
            <td><?php echo $_data['value'] ?></td>
        </tr>
 <?php endforeach; ?>

Comment: i think we should get additional data instead of attributes

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributes() on a non-object in /public_html/includes/src/Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Attributes.php on line 58

Comment: Back to a blank output with that one :/ attributename is collar_size

Comment: echo $this->helper('catalog/output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getCollarSize(), 'collar_size')

Comment: so remember you said you got output as no. so when the value is empty, it displays no. are you sure the value is not empty?

Comment: They have values as when I go into the product you can select, small,medium,large,xlarge. They all have 0 stock level as I've got stock system disabled. Not sure if that will effect it?

Comment: i think it is some setting in admin panel that is not letting you display. because code wise we have tried all of it..

Comment: Hmmm, do you have an email I can email to and give you an admin account to see if you can see anything? Its on a demo site so nothing to break!